# Oozie distributed scheduler

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am going through the oozie documentation and i understood that it is a distributed workflow scheduler .

Is it capable of scheduling workflows on the cluster where the oozie job has been submitted ? to rephrase, the oozie is capable of scheduling jobs or running scripts on any random node in the cluster, is it capable of taking an action on the client machine / edge node / other cluster ( for instance distcp ) .

Comment: PS : i also understood the distcp action is exception, which can be used to copy the files between different cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oozie itself is *not* distributed; the service runs on an "edge node" (a machine that has all the Hadoop libraries and config but does not run jobs or store HDFS files) and uses a database, typically MySQL, to store all jobs definition and state.

Oozie **coordinators** define when and how a workflow must be triggered.

Oozie **workflows** are Direct Acyclic Graphs (DAG) i.e. chains of simple steps - some steps can be executed in parallel, the chaining of steps can be conditional, but there are no loops *(that's what the A means in DAG)*.

Some trivial steps (e.g. send an e-mail) are done directly by Oozie, but all the rest is translated into YARN jobs - and then YARN runs these jobs on random modes. These jobs can be really "distributed", or not (e.g. a Shell Action is translated into a single Mapper, that runs the Oozie bootstrap JAR, that runs a shell interpreter, that runs the script provided -- in the end that's parallel processing of just 1 process... duh)

Note that a single Oozie service can run jobs on **multiple clusters**, that's why each workflow must specify a NameNode and a JobTracker *(a ResourceManager actually with YARN)*

You may want to browse that old, but comprehensive tutorial in 14 chapters:
http://hadooped.blogspot.fr/2013/06/apache-oozie-part-1-workflow-with-hdfs.html

Comment: This probes another question,  does oozie server exist in client or edge machine? Is it practical to have workflow Job point to two mapreduce jobs those can have two entirely different job tracker urls thus pointing to two different cluster? From workflow xml, it seems possible.

Comment: **(a)** just like any app, you can install it on a VM for test purposes, but the whole point of having a Scheduler in Prod is to have it running non-stop -- and with High Availability *(active/passive w/ ZooKeeper)* if possible **(b)** Oozie was developed by Yahoo, and AFAIK Yahoo uses it to run / coordinate many large clusters -- with a stress on *coordinate* (think about main workflow running in source cluster, containing sub-workflows targeted at other clusters downstream)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done, It's a data-aware service to orchestrate dependencies between jobs running on Hadoop.
Which includs HDFS, Pig, Hive, Python, Shell,Map Reduce Java, SSH, DISTCP, Custom Action Executor known as UDF as well.

Ref: [BLOG](http://hadooped.blogspot.in/2013/09/apache-oozie-part-12-passing-output.html) you can check as a sample usefull, many more are there, which describes more about the use